# How to avoid using exceptions, as a form of control flow, to jump through through deeply nested function calls?

Tags: c++, nested

I've currently been using custom exceptions to achieve the goal of jumping through deeply nested function calls, to get to a specific function in the call chain. For example, consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct label {};

void B();
void C();
void D();

void A() {
    return B();
}

void B() { // I want to jump to the level of the B function in the call-chain.
    try {
        return C();
    }
    catch(const label& e) {
        std::cout << "jumped to b function" << std::endl;
    }
}

void C() {
    return D();
}

void D() {
    throw label();
}

int main() {
    A();
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the above example is extremely contrived, and is simply for illustration purposes. In my actual code, I'm using this technique in a recursive-decent parser to recover from syntactical errors. Also note that I'm not using exceptions to jump around to different functions, like a glorified `goto`. *I'm using the custom exception to **always jump to one** specific function near the top of the call chain*.

The above code does work fine, but reading some of the top posts on the question [*Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?* (on the Software Engineering site)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why), suggested that using exceptions in such a manner as the above scenario does, is consider an anti-pattern, and there are usually better was to accomplish one's goal.

Is my usage of a custom exception above appropriate? If not, what is a more reasonable way to accomplish my goal while avoiding using exactions as a form control flow? (Also, although I tagged this question as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) since that's what I'm writing my parser in, I suppose this is a more language-agnostic question.)

Comment: Why not just return _errors_ and have `B` handle them? So say `C` tries to do something, if it fails it returns an error which `B` handles. Otherwise, `C` calls `D`, and if _that_ fails it returns an error back to `B` again.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using exceptions. They are a core, fundamental feature of C++. Having said that; with `std::optional` and `std::variant` in C++17 make it much easier to declare functions that may return different results in different situations; and in many cases it's possible to use this to achieve the same functionality that exceptions provide.

Comment: @Tas The problem with using that method, as I said in my question, is that the example I gave is very simplified. In my actually code, there are several places in each function where I would need to check and return errors, and this seemed overly cumbersome.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, that could be a viable option. But as I was telling Tas, there are several places in each function where I would need to check and return some constant denoting an error. Using a single custom exception seemed easier.

Comment: If you're using it to recover from literally exceptional circumstances it's fine. If you're using it as a way to jump out of nested functions under normal circumstances, you can probably find a more idiomatic design.

Comment: That's what I do. I guess I need to check more (e.g. `if (D() == fail) return fail;` for `B` to handle, rather than just have `D();` and if it throws return is already handled. I like it's clearer in `C()` to see that the function may return early after a call to `D()`, whereas by throwing it's not easy to see that `(void)D();` won't execute flawlessly and then `C()` will continue

Comment: @patatahooligan Well when my parser encounters a syntax error, I guess that _could_ be consider exceptional. But the line seems somewhat gray, so I wanted to know if there was a more idiomatic approach that was still fairly simple. If push comes to shove though, I could just do what Tas outlined in his first comment.

Comment: Maybe coroutines fit your use case? There are even macro-based C coroutines, based on Duff's device. See e.g. https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html I have used those, macros are ugly, but the coroutines work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Part 1:  - Nested Function Stack Calls With Exceptions.

---

This may not fit your particular or exact needs, however I'm willing to share this example as I think that it may provide some insight and that it is related to your current situation.

I have a set of classes that are integrated together that handle multiple common tasks. The following set of classes include `BlockProcess`, `BlockThread`, `FileHandlers`, `ExceptionHandler`, `Logger` and a `Utility` class. There are several files here and please keep in mind that this light weight project is targeted towards `Windows` and that I am using Visual Studio 2017 with pre compiled headers.

I'm sure one can strip out any `windows` dependent code easily and replace with their equivalent system, architecture & environment includes and functionality.

> *I am also using a namespace called `demo` that wraps all the classes & functions in this small project; any user should replace this namespace with their own namespace name.*

The main purpose of this is the design process of how I typically handle `exceptions` when the `stack calls` are nested quite deep.

These sets of classes not only allow control of Logging information, warnings & errors to the console with different settings for different types of messages, but also gives the ability to log the contents to a file.

This type of construct is very handy and versatile while being in the process of developing 3D Graphics Applications which can become very intense in their code base.

I can not take full credit for this code as a majority of this was inspired and designed by `Marek A. Krzeminski, MASc` which can be seen [here](https://www.marekknows.com/about.php?section=visualArts) yet I believe that it is the concepts and the use of this code that is important.

---

**Main Entry Point:**

> *`main.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BlockProcess.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Utility.h"

//struct label {}; // Instead of throwing this struct in D() I'm throwing the ExceptionHandler

void B();
void C();
void D();

void A() {
    return B();
}

void B() {
    using namespace demo;

    try {
        return C();
    } catch ( ... ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed for some reason.";
        Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_INFO );
        Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_WARNING );
        Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
        Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
    }
}

void C() {
    return D();
}

void D() {
    using namespace demo;

    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed for some reason.";
    throw ExceptionHandler( strStream ); // By Default will log to file; otherwise pass false for second param.
}

int _tmain( int iNumArgs, _TCHAR* pArugmentText[] ) {
    using namespace demo;

    try {
        Logger log( "logger.txt" );

        A();

        // Prevent Multiple Start Ups Of This Application
        BlockProcess processBlock( "ExceptionManager.exe" );
        if ( processBlock.isBlocked() ) {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << "ExceptionManager is already running in another window." << std::endl;
            throw ExceptionHandler( strStream, false );
        }

        Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();

    } catch ( ExceptionHandler& e ) {
        std::cout << "Exception Thrown: " << e.getMessage() << std::endl;
        Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();
        return RETURN_ERROR;

    } catch ( ... ) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " Caught Unknown Exception" << std::endl;
        Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();
        return RETURN_ERROR;
    }

    return RETURN_OK;
}
```

---

[image: Image Results:]

---

As you can see from the images above I was able to generate a log file of the info, warnings, errors etc., and if you look at the 2 consoles they were running simultaneously and the 2nd or lower cmd window is throwing the exception since I used the `BlockProcess` class to manage only a single instance of this running application. This is a very versatile design. The messages or thrown errors are being generated.

Now if you do not want execution to stop because of a specific value of a variable, the return of a function, if statement etc. instead of throwing an `ExceptionHandler` you can easily just create an `ostringstream` object, populate it with the needed iformation and you can pass that to `Logger` with the default option of saving to the Log file turned on or passing `false` as the last param. You can even set what type of message through the logger's types.

So to answer your question if this is anti-pattern? I honestly do not think it is if you carefully design your project and know where & when to throw messages.

---

**ExceptionHandler:**

> *`ExceptionHandler.h`*

```
#ifndef EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H
#define EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H

namespace demo {

class ExceptionHandler final {
private:
    std::string strMessage_;
public:
    explicit ExceptionHandler( const std::string& strMessage, bool bSaveInLog = true );
    explicit ExceptionHandler( const std::ostringstream& strStreamMessage, bool bSaveInLog = true );

    ~ExceptionHandler() = default;
    ExceptionHandler( const ExceptionHandler& c ) = default;

    const std::string& getMessage() const;

    ExceptionHandler& operator=( const ExceptionHandler& c ) = delete;
};

} // namespace demo

#endif // !EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H
```

> *`ExceptionHandler.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ExceptionHandler.h"
#include "Logger.h"

namespace demo {

ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler( const std::string& strMessage, bool bSaveInLog ) :
strMessage_( strMessage ) {
    if ( bSaveInLog ) {
        Logger::log( strMessage_, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
    }
}

ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler( const std::ostringstream& strStreamMessage, bool bSaveInLog ) :
strMessage_( strStreamMessage.str() ) {
    if ( bSaveInLog ) {
        Logger::log( strMessage_, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
    }
}

const std::string& ExceptionHandler::getMessage() const {
    return strMessage_;
}

} // namespace demo
```

---

**Logger:**

> *`Logger.h`*

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include "Singleton.h"

namespace demo { 
class Logger final : public Singleton {
public:
    enum LoggerType {
        TYPE_INFO = 0,
        TYPE_WARNING,
        TYPE_ERROR,
        TYPE_CONSOLE,
    }; // LoggerType

private:
    std::string strLogFilename_;
    unsigned   uMaxCharacterLength_;

    std::array<std::string, 4> aLogTypes_;
    const std::string          strUnknownLogType_;

    HANDLE hConsoleOutput_;
    WORD   consoleDefaultColor_;

public:
    explicit Logger( const std::string& strLogFilename );
    virtual ~Logger();

    static void log( const std::string& strText, LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );
    static void log( const std::ostringstream& strStreamText, LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );
    static void log( const char* szText, LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );

    Logger( const Logger& c ) = delete;
    Logger& operator=( const Logger& c ) = delete;
}; 

} // namespace demo 

#endif // !LOGGER_H
```

> *`Logger.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "BlockThread.h"
#include "TextFileWriter.h"

namespace demo {

static Logger* s_pLogger = nullptr;
static CRITICAL_SECTION s_criticalSection;
static const WORD WHITE_ON_RED = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED; // White Text On Red Background

Logger::Logger( const std::string& strLogFilename ) :
Singleton( TYPE_LOGGER ),
strLogFilename_( strLogFilename ),
uMaxCharacterLength_( 0 ),
strUnknownLogType_( "UNKNOWN" ) {
    // Oder must match types defined in Logger::Type enum
    aLogTypes_[0] = "Info";
    aLogTypes_[1] = "Warning";
    aLogTypes_[2] = "Error";
    aLogTypes_[3] = ""; // Console

    // Find widest log type string
    uMaxCharacterLength_ = strUnknownLogType_.size();
    for each ( const std::string& strLogType in aLogTypes_ ) {
        if ( uMaxCharacterLength_ < strLogType.size() ) {
             uMaxCharacterLength_ = strLogType.size();
        }
    }

    InitializeCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection ); // Enter critical section

    // Start log file
    TextFileWriter file( strLogFilename_, false, false );

    // Prepare console
    hConsoleOutput_ = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsoleOutput_, &consoleInfo );
    consoleDefaultColor_ = consoleInfo.wAttributes;

    s_pLogger = this;

    logMemoryAllocation( true );

} // Logger()

Logger::~Logger() {
    logMemoryAllocation( false );
    s_pLogger = nullptr;
    DeleteCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
} // ~Logger


void Logger::log( const std::string& strText, LoggerType eLogType ) {
    log( strText.c_str(), eLogType );
} 

void Logger::log( const std::ostringstream& strStreamText, LoggerType eLogType ) {
    log( strStreamText.str().c_str(), eLogType );
} 

void Logger::log( const char* szText, LoggerType eLogType ) {
    if ( nullptr == s_pLogger ) {
        std::cout << "Logger has not been initialized, can not log " << szText << std::endl;
        return;
    } 

    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection ); // Enter critical section

    std::ostringstream strStream;

    // Default White Text On Red Background
    WORD textColor = WHITE_ON_RED;

    // Choose log type text string, display "UNKNOWN" if eLogType is out of range
    strStream << std::setfill( ' ' ) << std::setw( s_pLogger->uMaxCharacterLength_ );

    try {
        if ( TYPE_CONSOLE != eLogType ) {
            strStream << s_pLogger->aLogTypes_.at( eLogType );
        }
        if ( TYPE_WARNING == eLogType ) {
            // Yellow
            textColor = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN;
        } else if ( TYPE_INFO == eLogType ) {
            // Green
            textColor = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
        } else if ( TYPE_CONSOLE == eLogType ) {
            // Cyan
            textColor = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE;
        }
    } catch ( ... ) {
        strStream << s_pLogger->strUnknownLogType_;
    }

    // Date & Time
    if ( TYPE_CONSOLE != eLogType ) {
        SYSTEMTIME time;
        GetLocalTime( &time );

        strStream << " [" << time.wYear << "."
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wMonth << "."
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wDay << " "
            << std::setfill( ' ' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wHour << ":"
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wMinute << ":"
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wSecond << "."
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 3 ) << time.wMilliseconds << "] ";
    }
    strStream << szText << std::endl;

    // Log message
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( s_pLogger->hConsoleOutput_, textColor );
    std::cout << strStream.str();

    // Save same message to file
    try {
        TextFileWriter file( s_pLogger->strLogFilename_, true, false );
        file.write( strStream.str() );
    } catch ( ... ) {
        // Ignore, not saved in log file
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " failed to write to file: " << strStream.str() << std::endl;
    }

    // Reset to default color
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( s_pLogger->hConsoleOutput_, s_pLogger->consoleDefaultColor_ );
}

} // namespace demo
```

> *`Singleton.h`*

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

namespace demo {

class Singleton {
public:
    // Number of items in enum type must match the number of items and order of items stored in s_aSingletons
    enum SingletonType {
        TYPE_LOGGER = 0, // MUST BE FIRST!
    }; // enum SingleType

private:
    SingletonType eType_;

public:
    Singleton( const Singleton& c ) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& c ) = delete;
    virtual ~Singleton();

protected:
    explicit Singleton( SingletonType eType );
    void logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const;
};

} // namespace demo

#endif // !SINGLETON_H
```

> *`Singleton.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Singleton.h"
#include "Logger.h"

namespace demo { 

struct SingletonInfo {
    const std::string strSingletonName;
    bool              isConstructed;

    SingletonInfo( const std::string& strSingletonNameIn ) :
        strSingletonName( strSingletonNameIn ),
        isConstructed( false ) 
    {}
}; 

// Order must match types defined in Singleton::SingletonType enum
static std::array<SingletonInfo, 1> s_aSingletons = { SingletonInfo( "Logger" ) };

Singleton::Singleton( SingletonType eType ) :
eType_( eType ) {
    bool bSaveInLog = s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_LOGGER ).isConstructed;

    try {
        if ( !s_aSingletons.at( eType ).isConstructed ) {
            // Test Initialize Order
            for ( int i = 0; i < eType; ++i ) {
                if ( !s_aSingletons.at( i ).isConstructed ) {
                    throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( i ).strSingletonName +
                                            " must be constructed before constructing " +
                                            s_aSingletons.at( eType ).strSingletonName,
                                            bSaveInLog );
                }
            }
            s_aSingletons.at( eType ).isConstructed = true;
        } else {
            throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( eType ).strSingletonName + 
                                    " can only be constructed once.", 
                                    bSaveInLog );
        }
    } catch ( std::exception& ) {
        // eType is out of range
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Invalid Singleton Type specified: " << eType;
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream, bSaveInLog );
    }
}

Singleton::~Singleton() {
    s_aSingletons.at( eType_ ).isConstructed = false;
} 

void Singleton::logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const {
    if ( isAllocated ) {
        Logger::log( "Created " + s_aSingletons.at( eType_ ).strSingletonName );
    } else {
        Logger::log( "Destroyed " + s_aSingletons.at( eType_ ).strSingletonName );
    }
} 

} // namespace demo
```

---

**For the reset of the project code see the 2nd provided answer:** *If you are looking to up-vote or accept please use this as the primary answer to vote upon, and please do not vote on the 2nd answer as it is only reference to this answer!*

---

Answer (score 0):

## Part 2:  - Nested Function Stack Calls With Exceptions.

---

**Note:** - *Please do not **VOTE** on this answer please refer to the first answer as this is just a continuation for reference of pertaining classes!*

You can find **Part 1** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393869/1757805). I had to split this into 2 separate answers for I was about 2,000 characters above the max character limit of 30,000. I do apologize for any inconvenience. However one can not `apply` this `ExceptionHandler` without the provided classes.

---

**FileHandlers:**

> *`FileHandler.h`*

```
#ifndef FILE_HANDLER_H
#define FILE_HANDLER_H

namespace demo {

class FileHandler {
protected:
    std::fstream fileStream_;
    std::string  strFilePath_;
    std::string  strFilenameWithPath_;

private:
    bool bSaveExceptionInLog_;

public:
    virtual ~FileHandler();

    FileHandler( const FileHandler& c ) = delete;
    FileHandler& operator=( const FileHandler& c ) = delete;

protected:
    FileHandler( const std::string& strFilename, bool bSaveExceptionInLog );
    void throwError( const std::string& strMessage ) const;
    void throwError( const std::ostringstream& strStreamMessage ) const;

    bool getString( std::string& str, bool appendPath );    
};

} // namespace demo

#endif // !FILE_HANDLER_H
```

> *`FileHandler.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FileHandler.h"

namespace demo {

FileHandler::FileHandler( const std::string& strFilename, bool bSaveExceptionInLog ) :
bSaveExceptionInLog_( bSaveExceptionInLog ),
strFilenameWithPath_( strFilename ) {
    // Extract path info if it exists
    std::string::size_type lastIndex = strFilename.find_last_of( "/\\" );
    if ( lastIndex != std::string::npos ) {
        strFilePath_ = strFilename.substr( 0, lastIndex );
    }

    if ( strFilename.empty() ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " missing filename", bSaveExceptionInLog_ ) );
    }
}

FileHandler::~FileHandler() {
    if ( fileStream_.is_open() ) {
         fileStream_.close();
    }
}

void FileHandler::throwError( const std::string& strMessage ) const {
    throw ExceptionHandler( "File [" + strFilenameWithPath_ + "] " + strMessage, bSaveExceptionInLog_ );
}

void FileHandler::throwError( const std::ostringstream& strStreamMessage ) const {
    throwError( strStreamMessage.str() );
}

bool FileHandler::getString( std::string& str, bool appendPath ) {
    fileStream_.read( &str[0], str.size() );
    if ( fileStream_.fail() ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Trim Right
    str.erase( str.find_first_of( char( 0 ) ) );

    if ( appendPath && !strFilePath_.empty() ) {
        // Add path if one exists
        str = strFilePath_ + "/" + str;
    }

    return true;
}

} // namespace demo
```

> *`TextFileReader.h`*

```
#ifndef TEXT_FILE_READER_H
#define TEXT_FILE_READER_H

#include "FileHandler.h"

namespace demo {

class TextFileReader : public FileHandler {
public:
    explicit TextFileReader( const std::string& strFilename );
    virtual ~TextFileReader() = default;

    std::string readAll() const;
    bool        readLine( std::string& strLine );

    TextFileReader( const TextFileReader& c ) = delete;
    TextFileReader& operator=( const TextFileReader& c ) = delete;
};

} // namespace demo

#endif // !TEXT_FILE_READER_H
```

> *`TextFileReader.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TextFileReader.h"

namespace demo {

TextFileReader::TextFileReader( const std::string& strFilename ) :
FileHandler( strFilename, true ) {
    fileStream_.open( strFilenameWithPath_.c_str(), std::ios_base::in );
    if ( !fileStream_.is_open() ) {
        throwError( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " can not open file for reading" ) );
    }
}

std::string TextFileReader::readAll() const {
    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << fileStream_.rdbuf();

    return strStream.str();
}

bool TextFileReader::readLine( std::string& strLine ) {
    if ( fileStream_.eof() ) {
        return false;
    }
    std::getline( fileStream_, strLine );
    return true;
}

} // namespace demo
```

> *`TextFileWriter.h`*

```
#ifndef TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H
#define TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H

#include "FileHandler.h"

namespace demo {

class TextFileWriter : public FileHandler {
public:
    explicit TextFileWriter( const std::string& strFilename, bool bAppendToFile, bool bSaveExceptionInLog = true );
    virtual ~TextFileWriter() = default;

    void write( const std::string& str );

    TextFileWriter( const TextFileWriter& c ) = delete;
    TextFileWriter& operator=( const TextFileWriter& c ) = delete;
};

} // namespace demo

#endif // !TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H
```

> *`TextFileWriter.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TextFileWriter.h"

namespace demo {

TextFileWriter::TextFileWriter( const std::string& strFilename, bool bAppendToFile, bool bSaveExceptionInLog ) :
FileHandler( strFilename, bSaveExceptionInLog ) {
    fileStream_.open( strFilenameWithPath_.c_str(),
                      std::ios_base::out | (bAppendToFile ? std::ios_base::app : std::ios_base::trunc) );

    if ( !fileStream_.is_open() ) {
        throwError( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " can not open file for writing" ) );
    }
}

void TextFileWriter::write( const std::string& str ) {
    fileStream_ << str;
}

} // namespace demo
```

---

**Processes & Threads**

> *`BlockProcess.h`*

```
#ifndef BLOCK_PROCESS_H
#define BLOCK_PROCESS_H

namespace demo {

class BlockProcess final {
private:
    HANDLE hMutex_;
public:
    explicit BlockProcess( const std::string& strName );
    ~BlockProcess();

    bool isBlocked() const;

    BlockProcess( const BlockProcess& c ) = delete;
    BlockProcess& operator=( const BlockProcess& c ) = delete;
};

} // namespace demo

#endif // !BLOCK_PROCESS_H
```

> *`BlockProccess.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BlockProcess.h"

namespace demo {

BlockProcess::BlockProcess( const std::string& strName ) {
    hMutex_ = CreateMutex( nullptr, FALSE, strName.c_str() );
} 

BlockProcess::~BlockProcess() {
    CloseHandle( hMutex_ );
}

bool BlockProcess::isBlocked() const {
    return (hMutex_ == nullptr || GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
}

} // namespace demo
```

> *`BlockThread.h`*

```
#ifndef BLOCK_THREAD_H
#define BLOCK_THREAD_H

namespace demo { 

class BlockThread final {
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION* pCriticalSection_;

public:
    explicit BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection );
    ~BlockThread();

    BlockThread( const BlockThread& c ) = delete;
    BlockThread& operator=( const BlockThread& c ) = delete;
}; 

} // namespace demo

#endif // !BLOCK_THREAD_H
```

> *`BlockThread.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BlockThread.h"

namespace demo { 

BlockThread::BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection ) {
    pCriticalSection_ = &criticalSection;
    EnterCriticalSection( pCriticalSection_ );
} 

BlockThread::~BlockThread() {
    LeaveCriticalSection( pCriticalSection_ );
}

} // namespace demo
```

---

**Utilities:**

> *`Utility.h`*

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

namespace demo { 

class Utility {
public:
    static void pressAnyKeyToQuit();

    static std::string  toUpper( const std::string& str );
    static std::string  toLower( const std::string& str );
    static std::string  trim( const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim = " \t\n\r" );

    static unsigned     convertToUnsigned( const std::string& str );
    static int          convertToInt( const std::string& str );
    static float        convertToFloat( const std::string& str );

    static std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty = true );

    Utility( const Utility& c ) = delete;
    Utility& operator=( const Utility& c ) = delete;

private:
    Utility(); // Private - Not A Class Object

    template<typename T>
    static bool stringToValue( const std::string& str, T* pValue, unsigned uNumValues );

    template<typename T>
    static T getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder );    
}; 

#include "Utility.inl"

} // namespace demo

#endif // !UTILITY_H
```

> *`Utility.inl`*

```
template<typename T>
static bool Utility::stringToValue( const std::string& str, T* pValue, unsigned uNumValues ) {
    int numCommas = std::count( str.begin(), str.end(), ',' );
    if ( numCommas != uNumValues - 1 ) {
        return false;
    }

    std::size_t remainder;
    pValue[0] = getValue<T>( str, remainder );

    if ( uNumValues == 1 ) {
        if ( str.size() != remainder ) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        std::size_t offset = remainder;
        if ( str.at( offset ) != ',' ) {
            return false;
        }

        unsigned uLastIdx = uNumValues - 1;
        for ( unsigned u = 1; u < uNumValues; ++u ) {
            pValue[u] = getValue<T>( str.substr( ++offset ), remainder );
            offset += remainder;
            if ( (u < uLastIdx && str.at( offset ) != ',') ||
                (u == uLastIdx && offset != str.size()) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

> *`Utility.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"

namespace demo {

void Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit() {
    std::cout << "\nPress any key to quit." << std::endl;
    _getch();
} 

std::string Utility::toUpper( const std::string& str ) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::toupper );
    return result;
}

std::string Utility::toLower( const std::string& str ) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::tolower );
    return result;
} 

std::string Utility::trim( const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim ) {
    std::basic_string<char>::size_type firstIndex = str.find_first_not_of( elementsToTrim );
    if ( firstIndex == std::string::npos ) {
        return std::string(); // Nothing Left
    }

    std::basic_string<char>::size_type lastIndex = str.find_last_not_of( elementsToTrim );
    return str.substr( firstIndex, lastIndex - firstIndex + 1 );
}

template<>
float Utility::getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder ) {
    return std::stof( str, &remainder );
}

template<>
int Utility::getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder ) {
    return std::stoi( str, &remainder );
}

template<>
unsigned Utility::getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder ) {
    return std::stoul( str, &remainder );
}

unsigned Utility::convertToUnsigned( const std::string& str ) {
    unsigned u = 0;
    if ( !stringToValue( str, &u, 1 ) ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to unsigned";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return u;
}

int Utility::convertToInt( const std::string& str ) {
    int i = 0;
    if ( !stringToValue( str, &i, 1 ) ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to int";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return i;
}

float Utility::convertToFloat( const std::string& str ) {
    float f = 0;
    if ( !stringToValue( str, &f, 1 ) ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to float";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return f;
}

std::vector<std::string> Utility::splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vResult;
    if ( strDelimiter.empty() ) {
        vResult.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return vResult;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while ( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if ( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            vResult.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if ( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimiter.size();
    }

    return vResult;
}

} // namespace demo
```

---

**Precompiled Headers:**

> *`stdafx.h`*

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

// Included files that typically will not change 
// during the development process of this application.   

// System - Architect Includes
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
//#include <mmsystem.h>

// Character & Basic IO
#include <conio.h> // for _getch()
#include <tchar.h>

//---------------------------------------------//
// Standard Library Includes

// Atomics, Regular Expressions, Localizations
#include <atomic>       // C++11
#include <clocale>
//#include <codecvt> // C++11 // Deprecated in C++17
#include <locale>
#include <regex>

// Numerics & Numeric Limits
#include <climits>
#include <cfloat>
#include <cstdint>      // C++11
#include <cinttypes>    // C++11
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <valarray>
#include <random>       // C++11
#include <numeric>
#include <ratio>        // C++11
#include <cfenv>        // C++11

// Strings, Streams & IO 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

// Thread Support
#include <thread>               // C++11
#include <mutex>                // C++11
#include <shared_mutex>         // C++14
#include <future>               // C++11
#include <condition_variable>   // C++11

// Containers
#include <array>         // C++11
#include <stack>
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>  // C++11
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map> // C++11
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>  // C++11
#include <vector>

// Algorithms, Iterators
#include <algorithm>      // Note* C++ 17 also has <execution>
#include <iterator>

// Dynamic Memory
#include <new>
#include <memory>
#include <scoped_allocator> // C++11

// Utilities
#include <bitset>
#include <ctime>        // Compatability with C style time formarts
#include <chrono>       // C++ 11 - C++ Time Utilities
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>  // C++11
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>    // C++11
#include <type_traits>  // C++11
#include <tuple>        // C++11
#include <utility>

// C++ 17
#include <any>
#include <filesystem>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>
#include <variant>    

// C++ 20
// #include <compare> 
// #include <charconv>
// #include <syncstream>

// 3rd Party Library Includes Here.

// User-Application Specific commonly used non changing headers.
#include "ExceptionHandler.h" 

namespace demo { 

enum ReturnCode {
    RETURN_OK = 0,
    RETURN_ERROR = 1,
}; // ReturnCode

extern const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED;
extern const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED_SHORT;

} // namespace demo

#endif // !STDAFX_H
```

> *`stdafx.cpp`*

```
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace demo {

const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED = static_cast<const unsigned>(-1);
const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED_SHORT = static_cast<const unsigned short>(-1);

} // namespace demo
```